# How to configure, Route 53 and Elastic load balancer that access instances in two different regions in Amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, load-balancing, amazon-route53

I have two autoscaled instances in two different regions, and I configured Elastic Load Balancing for those two.

and finally I configured geo dns in Route 53,  for two regions using CNAME alias.

Like below

```
(www.l.example.com. CNAME w.usa.example.com.)
(w.usa.example.com. A ALIAS xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com)
(www.l.example.com. CNAME w.sg.asia.example.com)
(w.sg.asia.example.com. AALIAS yyyyyyyyyyyy.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com)
```

how can I create record for example.com ???

Note :: if user open `example.com` in his browser from USA, it will route to US instance and from india, it will route to asia server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your CNAME record types to A and utilize Alias records.  Then you can alias example.com -> www.l.example.com.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html

Comment: It gives me error while creating A record.


The record set could not be saved because:
- Alias Target contains an invalid value.

Comment: Do you get the error when you try to convert "www.l.example.com. CNAME w.usa.example.com" to "www.l.example.com. ALIAS w.usa.example.com"?  You will want to make sure that you have the Alias radio button, right below type, set to yes.

Comment: Yes. I clicked on CNAME record, and changed to alias radio button to YES and I typed alias name "w.usa.example.com", it gives error "The record set could not be saved because: - Alias Target contains an invalid value."

Comment: Did you also change the type to A?

Comment: Now I changed to A record, it gives another error.

"RRSet of type A with DNS name www.l.example.com. is not permitted because a conflicting RRSet of type CNAME with the same DNS name already exists in zone example.com"

Comment: You will either need to do the update on both www.l.example.com resource records in the same batch using the API or delete the second record, update the first to A & alias and create the second record again as A & alias.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60554/discussion-between-imperalix-and-upendra).